# Resolving schemeless URLs in UIWebView constructed with loadHTMLString:

Tags: ios, url, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` that is being constructed with `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`. The content of this webview is somewhat arbitrary, and may include things like iframe to resources on the web, such as youtube video embeds. Youtube iframes generally use schemeless URls, which is presenting a problem. It seems as though because the web view was not initialized with a request, but rather static HTML, Webkit is not doing any scheme determination for these addition requests that need to be made for things like iframes. As such, iframes with schemeless `src` attributes are being loaded as local files, and thus failing.

Is there a better way of handling this than simply searching for URLs that appear to be schemeless with javascript and replacing them?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `nil` as the `baseURL`, the default scheme becomes `about` and the scheme-less resources will fail to load. The key to pass a HTTP URL, even an invalid URL, to `loadWithHTMLString:baseURL:`. For example:

```
NSString *html = @"<html><img src=\"//example.com/some_image.jpg\"></html>";
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost"]];
```

In my testing, I've found that simply passing `[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"]` works just fine.

Comment: I believe that impacts how documents are loaded when using relative URLs to locate files that *are* on the file system. Perhaps there's no way to handle both cases at once.